Is hierachical regression with aggressive p-deletion really much 'better' than stepwise?
In many medical science fields "hierarchical regression" is a popular method.
The approach is to break variables into categories, add one category of variables at a time and then remove before adding the next set of variables.
One defense I've seen of this is that since "field expertise chooses variables" it's less problematic. Certainly this can often be the case, depending how hierarchical regression is executed.
However, some groups/researchers, when doing hierarchical regression, insist on strictly p-deleting at very low thresholds (0.05 or even lower; I've had people tell me I have to delete at lower thresholds "to correct for multiple comparisons"). The process is: add category of vars --> toss out everything with p < 0.05 --> do the same with each category until done.
Does this particular approach to hierarchical regression not recreate most of the same problems with stepwise selection? The only thing field expertise is informing is the categories and their order; it's not being used to make a decision on to delete or not delete, which is being dictated by p-values much like it would be in stepwise.

the p-value is a red herring: the real question is "Does addition/deletion of a group instead of individual variables really improve stepwise regression?".

There is certainly a more principled way to include or exclude whole pre-defined groups of predictors: the group lasso. That has a big advantage over HR: penalizing the coefficients to minimize over-fitting.

A process that goes "add category of vars --> toss out everything with p < 0.05 --> do the same with each category until done" still replicates many (if not all) of the standard problems with stepwise methods.
At the end of the day, in this approach you are still running multiple versions of the same model, deleting variables based on p values, and then (and this is the really critical part) only reporting one final model. And so just as with stepwise methods you are distorting p values by running multiple versions of the same model but only reporting the one that has the most significant results.
So maybe this approach does a bit better in some ways, because there is some theoretical justification for the order you are including variables, but that doesn't address the fundamental problem of distorting p values.
The most defensible uses of "hierarchical regression" (which is also a terrible name because it sounds like it's talking about a form of HLM/multilevel modeling) that I have seen is when a researcher enters variables in blocks based on their theoretical understanding of their causal ordering, and then reports everything. So first you run a model that only includes demographics, then another which adds a block of variables measuring lifecycle choices (which could be informed by demographics), and then a block of variables indicating health effects (which could be informed by choices).  And then you report all of these models and/or discuss how the coefficients or R2 change  when new blocks of variables are included. This approach is better because 1) it is totally informed by theory, rather than p values and 2) it doesn't "hide" the additional models, but reports everything.

I think this is an interesting question, and I have considered how similarly problematic both methods can be with respect to hypothesis testing. This question probably verges on opinion-based, but I'll give my reasons with what I feel are strong justifications.
The major distinction between the two, as you know, is that stepwise holds the reigns with respect to the final model. In otherwise, it is completely automatic, but worse, it it's automatic nature is completely flawed. There is no theoretical underpinning linked to the model. It simply is whatever is barfed out of the regression after capitalizing on however many chance changes it makes to the final model. So in this respect, I consider stepwise to be a standard deviation or two worse than hierarchical regression. However, you are quite right that hierarchical regression suffers from major flaws that almost put it into the same category as stepwise.
First, it is much more prone to HARKing if it is not pre-registered beforehand, as one can just shuffle around the blocks as they please to get a desired result, and because this is the case, it offers up far too many researcher degrees of freedom than I like. I have yet to find a pre-registered HR, which leads me to believe that many are fishing expeditions where people just tap variables into blocks until they get what they want.
Second, the "chunks" of the model that get tested are almost always deemed worthy solely by virtue of $p$ values, which we all know can be an unreliable barometer for the "truth" in many ways. I've seen people accept statistically significant blocks as "superior" with near zero change in $\Delta R^2$ or other more meaningful differences in the model, which left me wondering what kind of answer the superior model gives us.
Third, there really doesn't seem to be any universally accepted rules on how blocks are accepted or rejected. As you already noted, some people seem to make up the playbook as they go along with anything in the model, right down to the $p$ values themselves. I've yet to see one done in a way that convinces me the model is correct. So I think they both tend to have poorly implemented procedures, stepwise is still the king of ugly model selection methods.
Now one can read through all of this and just say "this is just the consequence of bad actors and not the method itself." But I think the major purpose of the method lends itself to these side effects because it is built on only caring about flimsy $p$-value based decision making about the relative importance of effects (where interpretation of the actual coefficients in each block are often ignored anyway).
